# What is the reproductive success of a biting mosquito?

Tags: entomology, reproduction, fitness, mosquitoes

Female mosquito can lay ~50-100 eggs in each batch. It takes some time between the hatch and until the time the female mosquito bits. During this time many of them will die.

What is the average percentage of the eggs that mature (in other words, if a female mosquito lays one hundred eggs, how many of them will become grown females that bite)?

Answer (score 1):

The amount (percentage) of eggs to mature varies greatly and depends on many factors and off course varies by season.

The correct (but not really satisfying) answer is that from every 100 eggs, between 0 and 100 eggs will mature. On average, this number is greater than 1 (otherwise the species would go extinct), and much smaller than 100 (otherwise the world would drown in mosquitoes). Because the question doesn't include the complete lifecycle, it is not exactly 1, but greater than 1.

*Some explanation*
Mosquitoes lay eggs in water, and the larvae are easy prey for predatory invertebrates (larvae of dragonflies, beetles etc.) and fish. Many mosquito species choose small, isolated waters (like small pools and plant-pots) where there is likely to be little predation. This however carries a risk: these waters often dry out (reproductive succes 0%), offer little resources (reproductive succes low) and offer no shelter against an unforseen predator (reproductive succes low). If they choose wisely however, reproductive succes can be very high. Because of this large variation, an average number is really not so informative.

Comment: I think the number has to be almost exactly 1 (not more than 1) for the population to remain stable. And that's 1 maturing egg for the entire life of the female, not 1 per batch nor 1 per 100 eggs. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Stephen_Thomas The question is not about the complete lifecycle, so it must be greater than one.

Comment: So suppose the answer is 2. Then, for every batch, 2 females would reach maturity (and, we're assuming, breed). And for a complete lifecycle of, say, 5 egg-laying batches, 10 females would reach maturity. In that case the mosquito population would grow 10-fold at each generation. Clearly that can't be correct.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. My answer is indeed incorrect.